The sum of the signed stirling numbers times the factorials
The sum of interest is the following...
$$
\sum^{n}_{k=1} (k-1)!s(n,k)
$$
Where the $s(n,k)$ are the signed Stirling number of the first kind. The sum is very close to other identities involving the stirling numbers and produces a fairly slow growing sequence for something defined with combinatorics. I can't seem to work it the right way to get a form that is not a sum.

This is the Sterling transform of the (shifted) factorial.  See OEIS A089064.  That sequence differs from yours by alternating the sign and having an extra first element (since it uses the unshifted factorials).

Oh thank you! So this is a known sequence and it seems to be related to the expansion of the ln(ln(x)).
